# Как обозначить то, что приложение предполагается только для iPhone?

Tags: swift, xcode

Cейчас пишу приложению на Swift для iPhone и мне нужно сделать так что бы приложение предполагалось только для iPhone что бы его не пытались Apple при проверке скачивать на iPad. И когда оно выложиться в AppStore чтобы его могли скачивать только пользователи iPhone? помогите пожалуйста, где и как можно отключить iPad?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104157/how-to-change-iphone-ipad-app-to-iphone-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках проекта (Там где можно указать Display Name, Bundle Identifier и т.д) в разделе Deployment Info убрать галочку iPad.

[image]